# Override memcpy work in Debug but not in Release?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, overriding

I want to override the standard memcpy with what the one in the [AsmLib](http://agner.org/optimize/#asmlib) library.

The documentation says:

> If you use the "override" version of the asmlib library then you don’t have to modify the
>   program source code. All you have to do is to link the appropriate version of asmlib into your
>   project.

Which is what I have done, I have added "alibcof64o.lib" to additional dependencies, in both Debug and release configurations.

When I  compile in Debug, it works fine, when I look at the disassembly it will call the A_memcpy, with SSE instructions. However, when I compile with Release, it will not call A_memcpy, but the regular one.

Why?

Comment: Have you tried `/Oi-` compilation flag as the documentation suggests?

Comment: I missed that part! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Release mode includes optimizations. A lot of optimizations affect the way `memcpy` gets invoked.

For example, the number of bytes to be copied can be determined at compile time, it is a massive optimization not to call the generic `memcpy` implementation. Similarly, if the compiler can determine that the source and destinations are aligned, optimizations are possible beyond calling the default `memcpy`.

In any event, the standard `memcpy` is already heavily optimized for all platforms, including using SSE2, so I'm not sure why you're bothering.

Comment: Well, the AsmLib contains some optimization which the default implementation doesn't use, e.g. string functions with SSE4.2. I assume these will suffer from the same problem. I only choose memcpy as an first try as it is most common.

Comment: Also looking at the benchmarks included with asmlib, the memcpy there is between 10%-500% faster than the default visual studio 2008 one.

Comment: I doubt it's possible for the AsmLib optimizations to outweigh the optimizations that are only possible in the invocation. Any `memcpy` replacement will always need a function call and return, always require putting the length in a register, never permit taking advantage of cases where the size is known at compile time (or known to be a multiple of 2 or 4 at compile time), never permit taking advantage of alignments known at compile time, and so on. It would take a lot of micro-optimizations to outweigh that.